# I thought I had improved a post by editing it, but my suggested edit was rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

[My suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23004430) was rejected. As I said I was trying to improve the post. This is the reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability

If this is correctly reviewed, please suggest what should I keep in mind while suggesting edits in future.

Comment: That edit introduced as much mistakes as it fixed. It's not an improvement.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Could you clarify the mistake that is introduced for us non-native speakers? To me at least the title seems better than it was before the edit...

Comment: @user000001: _"when running the code there is an error in the module which says tensorflow module does not exist even though I have installed the module from tensorflow."_ lacks the required punctuation that'd make it readable. The edits in that first paragraph aren't an improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I saw this question and saw that the question hadn't been edited to fix the errors you were trying to fix. I've since addressed those issues in two [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56122252/revisions) to the post.

As your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23004430) summary was "grammar mistakes" I'll concentrate on the grammar and spelling changes you made/did not make.

Reading down the post, here are some things that I picked up that your edit didn't correct.

- Firstly, the title. You changed "*How to using Tensorflow in python?*" to "*How to use Tensorflow in python?*". This is better, but "how to..." is a statement, not a question. See, e.g. [*'How to' vs 'How do I'*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56625/109567) for more.

  It's [advised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/284827) that you write question titles in question form, e.g. "How can I {x}" vs. "How to {x}" because "How to {x}" reads like the title of a tutorial, not the title of a question.
- You've not corrected the spelling of [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) (capital T, capital F) in the places it's used in text (the title, first block of text). Likewise with [Python](https://www.python.org/).
- You then correctly changed "there is the code:" to "Here is the code:" but didn't change "and that this output:" (which doesn't make sense). My edit changed it to "and here is the output:".
- As [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) pointed out in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384965/i-thought-i-had-improved-a-post-by-editing-it-but-my-suggested-edit-was-rejecte#comment696232_384965),

  > "when running the code there is an error in the module which says tensorflow module does not exist even though I have installed the module from tensorflow." lacks the required punctuation that'd make it readable. The edits in that first paragraph aren't an improvement.

  After that comment I changed it to

  > When running the code there is an error in the module stating that the TensorFlow module does not exist even though I have installed the module.

  which hopefully is more readable.

---

I would not reject an edit for not getting rid of a few stray lines of whitespace, but I saw that the original code had some duplicated blank lines in, which I trimmed out.

Your suggested edit was not terrible - it just didn't correct enough of the post to warrant acceptance. If I reviewed your suggested edit, I would probably have rejected and edited it.

Comment: okay, got it. I missed few things it could have been done better by me.

Comment: Yeah - I think if you'd fixed a few more things your edit might have been accepted. I sometimes accept and edit suggested edits with lots of good changes but leave the post with a few issues still.

Answer (score 7):

To be honest I'd have rejected this edit as well. Putting a edit request with mostly minor grammatical changes is not really a good use of time and review points for those who are working the review queue. It also introduces a couple of new mistakes. Going through the changes one by one:

Old Title

> How to **using** Tensorflow in python?

New Title

> How to **use** Tensorflow in python?

No qualms there, though I would have also made **P**ython start with a capital letter as per their [style guide](https://docs.python.org/3.1/documenting/style.html):

> **Python**
>
> The name of our favorite programming language is always capitalized.

---

Old

> there is an error in the module **where the** tensorflow module does not exist even though I have installed the module from tensorflow

New

> there is an error in the module **which says** tensorflow module does not exist even though I have installed the module from tensorflow

I'd argue the old revision still makes sense, but I'd leave a comment asking OP to copy-and-paste the **exact** error message and stacktrace if applicable. This error could then be moved into a quote block (or code block in the case of a stacktrace).

As Cerbrus points out [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384965/i-thought-i-had-improved-a-post-by-editing-it-but-my-suggested-edit-was-rejecte/384966#comment696232_384965), this paragraph could also do with a bit of punctuation to break it up.

> *"when running the code there is an error in the module which says tensorflow module does not exist even though I have installed the module from tensorflow."* lacks the required punctuation that'd make it readable. The edits in that first paragraph aren't an improvement.

---

Old:

> **Can you help me** resolve the error?

New:

> **How to** resolve the error?

Leaving aside the fact that the new sentence is grammatically incorrect (*"How do I resolve this error?"* would be a better way of wording it), this sentence doesn't add anything to the question and should be removed entirely.

---

Old

> **there** is the code:

New

> **Here** is the code:

Fair enough, but I'd still argue this is too minor a change to put through the review queue. Save it for when you have 2k rep.

---

One other change I'd have made would be to use bullet points to list the dependency versions like so:

> The tensorflow dependences I am using are:
>
> - tensorflow 1.13.1
> - tensorflow-estimator 1.13.0

So yes, the reviewers were correct to reject this particular edit in my opinion, but don't let that put you off. Save the more "minor" edits for those who can edit without needing review (>2k rep), but if you can substantially improve a different question then go for it.